# Development Kit suggestions

Tags: embedded, hardware, usb, wifi

Working on a PoC of a project that streams data from USB via Wifi:

I need a development kit with WLan (preferably 802.11g) and HighSpeed USB device.
Don't mind the CPU type, memory size etc.
(Even a kit with only Ethernet 100M will do)

If anyone can recommend one or even suggest a place to ask, I will be most obliged.

Regards,
Murkin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're ok with linux and adding a third party wifi module, you might want to look at the ATSTK5xx.  Mouser sells them for as low as eighty bucks and the wifi might run you another fifty.  The Atmel FAE is probably a good place to start.

If you're willing to spend a bit more money, you might also look at buglabs.net and gumstix.com

Comment: Excellent answer ! The last two appear a bit more expensive than what I have found so far, but the way they look might give an extra "bang" during presentations.

Answer (score 2):

I would look at the gunstix boards, and the beagle board.  Both use linux and have various peripherals you can attach.

A little more expensive are the omap3530 eval board from LogicPD which I believe has wifi, bluetooth, and usb hw on the board.